# Node.js Open page with cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm wonder about one question. For example:
I have cookies for domain https://google.com (or any another)
And I have Node.js server (expressjs or any) with url http://localhost/google.
When I'm open http://localhost/google I want to see https://google.com WITH cookies (WITHOUT redirect and iframes) BUT I don't want to expose cookies to the user.

One more example for better understanding:
I have cookies. And I want to open page with cookies on my server (and see it in browser) BUT I don't want to expose cookies to the user.

Its simple idea to share one account with users without sharing credentials or cookies. Can it be done ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Cookies are bound to a domain so "localhost" will not have "google.com" cookies. Is that your problem?

Comment: Problem not with this. I know how cookies works. I want to display google.com with active account through the page on my server. Eg. You open http://localhost/google and see google.com with MY account.